# Can I extend the State class and override setState

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I kept running into the issue where you call `setState` when the widget is not mounted (especially after a data fetch). My question is:

Can I extend the `State` class and override `setState` like so

```
abstract class MountedState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if(mounted) super.setState(fn);
  }
}
```

I did this and it worked. I just want to know if it is not ideal or I am not supposed to

```
Future<void> fetchSubjectsAndClasses() async {
    try {
      Response res = await TeachersAPI.classesAndSubjects();
      classes = res.data;
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

This is my data fetch that causes the issue. It gets called on `initState`

Comment: If you're consistently calling `setState` when the widget is not mounted, you're likely doing something wrong.

Comment: I think like @ChristopherMoore. Usually this should not happen.

Comment: It's not consistently calling `setState`. I have widgets that make network requests to get data. Then call setState after the data has been fetched. But the user might have popped the route before the data returns. In which, setState will then be called but of course the widget is no longer available so it throws an error @ChristopherMoore @NiklasLehnfeld

Comment: I didn't say you were consistently calling `setState`. I said you were consistently calling `setState` *when the widget is not mounted*. From what I can tell, you seem to be being doing some kind of async call without `FutureBuilder`, which does not have the problems you describe. You need to share what you're doing that generates errors without your special class.

Comment: I am fetching data without `FutureBuilder`. Then updating the UI once I am done fetching

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You **should** be putting what's updated by `setState` *within* `setState`. I posted an answer showing how to use `FutureBuilder` in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal. You should be using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) when dealing with async functions that deal with the UI. It's not mandatory, but it takes care of the more annoying parts of updating the UI with `Future` data.

You should obtain your future in `initState` and store it in the `State` of the widget. Then pass that to your `FutureBuilder` in `build`:

```dart
Future myFuture;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
   myFuture = futureCall();
}

@override
Widget build() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: myFuture,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        //Show widget that has data
      }
      else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        //Show widget that has error
      }
      else {
        //Show widget while loading
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! However, is there any reason why I shouldn't use the method described in my question?

Comment: @NduJay It prevents problems like the one you currently have and it's significantly easier in almost all situations. It can also be more efficient depending on the surround elements.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. For example, the solution also prevents those issues and I can easily use it in my Widget by extending my `MountedState` instead of `State`. Is there any specific reason why I shouldn't use the custom `MountedState` class. Thanks again

Comment: @NduJay It's significantly easier to use and can be more efficient. Additionally, your current check may not work if the widget is destroying and not unmounted yet.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @NduJay What you're doing isn't *wrong*, but it's boilerplate.

Comment: I have updated the code to use `FutureBuilder` and it still works so I guess it's okay